# Position div margin top 30px but keep margin in centre using margin auto?

Tags: html, css, margin

i am having a problem getting my div to move down my page by 30px / adding a margin to the top of my div by 30px. My div is aligned in the centre of the page using margin auto.

however when i try to add this line of code:
margin: 30px auto 0 auto;

no top margin is being displayed? please can someone show me what i am doing wrong? Thanks,

```
#content_other{
width:790px;
height: auto;
font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Tahoma, Verdana, Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
position:relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding:20px;
background:#fff;
border: 1px solid #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;


}
```

html:

```
<div id="content_other">

<html form here>

</div>
```

Comment: it works for me in google chrome

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine :) Yet let me know in which browser you are getting that issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code.
Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jboto204/). The margin is added to the top
I used this HTML

```
<div id="content_other">
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If other things on the page are influencing your overall page CSS then try adding to the `margin-top` an Important to promote it and override other things which might be cancelling that rule.

```
margin: 30px auto 0 auto !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the containers around it so we would need to see full HTML.  You could add an interior wrapper and float it:

```
<div id="content_other">
    <div id="float-wrap">
        <html form here>
    </div>
</div>

#float-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```